# How to recursively find folders on a Linux system, that contains folders only?

Tags: linux, find, directory-listing

I'm trying to work out a command that recursively finds directories that only contain one or more directories on the same level. Preferably with the `find` command. Like `find . -type d`.

For example, in the following file structure:

```
/tmp/folder1/folder1a/test.jpg
/tmp/folder1/file1a.tmp
/tmp/folder2/folder2a/test.jpg
/tmp/folder3/folder3a/
/tmp/folder3/folder3b/file.jpg
```

I'd like to hit on `folder2` and `folder3` only since it does not contain files itself, it only contains folders (with files).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`comm -23 <(find . -type d ! -empty | sort -u) <(find . -type f -printf '%h\n' | sort -u)`

This is a list of non-empty folders (at least one thing in it) excluding those that contain any files. If you also want to exclude things like pipes and symlinks you could use `! -type d` instead of `-type f`. It cannot be done in a single find statement because find cannot match on complex content criteria (this is not XPath).

Answer (score 2):

If I get you right, this should do it:

```
find . -type d ! -empty -exec sh -c '\
[ -z "`find "$1" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 ! -type d -print -quit`" ]\
' sh {} \; -print
```

Because of `-empty`, `-maxdepth`, `-mindepth` and `-quit`, which are not in POSIX, the solution may not work in your OS (`-print -quit` is only to speed things up, you can omit this fragment; `-maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1` is important though).

The trick is to run a separate shell for every non-empty directory, that checks (non-recursively) if the directory doesn't contain any non-directory. This is done with `-exec sh … \;`, it acts as a test here. If the directory doesn't contain any non-directory then the output of the inner `find` is empty, so the test (`[ -z … ]`) returns exit status `0`, `sh` returns `0`, `-exec` is true.